# iOS: Symbols for system libraries are unavailable for "iPhone 12(14.2)"

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, ios-simulator, instruments

I am trying to check my app for memory leaks in Instruments v12.2. However I am seeing a warning **Symbols for system libraries are unavailable for "iPhone 12(14.2)"**.

I have tried testing it with different simulators but getting the same warning and no leaks are displayed even I have explicitly added a leak in my code.

I have added a picture for reference.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what causes it, but I had two versions of Xcode, i just closed the one that was failing(12.2) and opened the other one (12.5), this fixed it.